# Eclipse CDT does not parse <variant> include file correctly

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, variant

I know, screenshots should not be provided as MCVE but here I want to point out the error.

[image]

Moving the focus into the include file  I see then the problem:

[image]

I have set up Eclipse in that way that it folds all inactive preprocessor directives. So, it is clear Eclipse does not have defined the correct value for preprocessor #define `__cplusplus` [the - for Eclipse - inactive code has also a gray background, line #34].

I am using `gcc 7.3` with `-std=c++17`.

What am I missing and how can I set this `__cplusplus` to the proper value?
This small MCVE of course compiles.

**Technical data:**

> Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
>
> Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
>
> Build id: 20180405-1200

Eclipse does not support apparently C++17 natively so I had to set in *Project* -> *Properties* -> *C/C++ Build* -> *Settings* -> *GCC C++ Compiler* -> *Dialect* -> *Other dialect flags* `-std=c++17`

Comment: Eclipse's parser does not support C++17 features yet (and there are some C++14 features it does not yet sypport, either), so if the `<variant>` header is making use of such newer features, Eclipse may not be able to parse it correctly.

Comment: @HighCommander4 Is there at least a workaround, like I set this `__cplusplus` to `201703L`? Now, the half source is marked red because of this! Any information when it should be supported?

Comment: @HighCommander4 I am using the `@suppress` directive. I think I can live with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first hurdle is to get Eclipse to recognize that the code is being compiled in C++17 mode.

There are several ways to do this, but the one I've found to be most reliable is to go to `Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> Providers tab -> CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings` and add `-std=c++17` to the "Command to get compiler specs". Then do `Project -> C/C++ Index -> Rebuild`.

That should get your trivial example to resolve without errors:

```
#include <variant>

std::variant<int, double> foo;
```

However, as soon as you try to call a function on the variant:

```
#include <variant>

std::variant<int, double> foo;

std::size_t i = foo.index();
```

the function call `index()` in this case is marked as an error.

This is because Eclipse's parser doesn't understand most C++17 features yet. In particular, it can't parse **fold expressions**, which are used fairly heavily in the definition of libstdc++'s (the standard library that ships with GCC) implementation of `variant`. As a result, Eclipse can't parse the `variant` class definition and thus does not know what members `variant` has.

A workaround, as you've discovered, is to use `@suppress` to suppress the false-positive errors you get as a result. Note that you will also suffer some impairment in terms of editor features, such as not getting code completion on objects whose type is `variant`.

You could consider [contributing](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/contributing) to Eclipse's C++ parser ([this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=508653) tracks support for fold expressions).